# Return just buckets size of aggregation query - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using an aggregation query on elasticsearch 2.1, here is my query:

```
"aggs": { 
    "atendimentos": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_parent",
        "size" : 0
      }
    }
  }
```

The return is like that:

```
"aggregations": {
        "atendimentos": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "1a92d5c0-d542-4f69-aeb0-42a467f6a703",
                    "doc_count": 12
                },
                {
                    "key": "4e30bf6d-730d-4217-a6ef-e7b2450a012f",
                    "doc_count": 12
                }.......
```

It return 40000 buckets, so i have a lot of buckets in this aggregation, i just want return the buckets size, but i want something like that:

```
buckets_size: 40000
```

Guys, how return just the buckets size?

Well, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "atendimentos": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_parent"
      }
    },
    "count":{
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "_parent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It may return something like that:

```
"aggregations": {
    "aads": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "aa",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
       {
          "key": "bb",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "count": {
      "value": 2
    }
  }
```

EDIT: More info here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "type_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "type"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)